# How to make csv rows into separate JSON files that contain objects?

Tags: python, arrays, json, csv, object

I am currently trying to turn my csv rows into JSON files with objects opposed to arrays. My issue is that when running my code, I am getting files with arrays instead of objects.

```
import csv 
import json 

JSON_ENTRIES_THRESHOLD = 1  # modify to whatever you see suitable

def write_json(json_object, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
        json.dump(json_object, jsonf)  # note the usage of .dump directly to a file 
descriptor

def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    jsonObject = []

with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 
    filename_index = 0

    for row in csvReader:
        jsonObject.append(row)
        if len(jsonObject) >= JSON_ENTRIES_THRESHOLD:
            # if we reached the treshold, write out
            write_json(jsonObject, f"jsonFilePath-{filename_index}.json")
            filename_index += 1
            jsonObject = []
        
    # Finally, write out the remainder
    write_json(jsonObject, f"jsonFilePath-{filename_index}.json")
```

Comment: As you're using `DictReader` you will get `dict` objects iterating over it, so `write_json(row, ...)`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some sample rows from the CSV file.

Comment: Your `jsonObject` is a Python list will be converted into a JSON array by `json.dump()`.